# displaying tasks with today's deadline in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I was looking to display tasks with today's deadline but couldn't find anything helpful.

How do I achieve being able to see / arrange tasks and todo's based on date when I have actually written them down based on task type.

One example is :

```
* TOPIC :  SOMETHING SOMETHING SYSTEM
** TODO Get the documentation ready
   DEADLINE: <2013-04-04 Thu>
```

There are several such TODO's in each topic and several topics.

Comment: Have you tried the agenda? `M-x org-agenda`, not bound by default but you will have bound it to `C-c a` if you followed the tutorial. That is your go-to place for summarised tasks and it should certainly include tasks with deadline today (and scheduled for today).

Comment: I had tried that. I get stuck where it shows the agenda with date and then only the date. I can't see the tasks within the deadline with that date. I'll go through the tutorial. I was wondering if people had similar problems

Comment: Give one sample of your task, i.e., how you define the deadline and schedule.

Comment: @gongzhitaao : edited the post to add an example

Comment: Did you set your ``org-agend-files``? ``C-h v org-agenda-files`` to see its content.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the file with the item is in `org-agenda-files`.

You can add it to the agenda using `C-c [` and check to ensure it is included using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>org-agenda-files<kbd>RET</kbd>